# List with function C#

Tags: c#, list

I want to add a list in a class with object and call this function in my main to add these objects in a list.

My class :

```
namespace SuiviEntretienMoto
{
    class Marque
    {
        private string nomMarque;

        public Marque(string nomMarque)
        {
            this.nomMarque = nomMarque;
        }

        public List<Marque> lesMarques()
        {
            List<Marque> lesMarques = new List<Marque>();
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Beta"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Gas Gas"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Honda"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Husaberg"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Husqvarna"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Kawasaki"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("KTM"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Sherco"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Suzuki"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("TM"));
            lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Yamaha"));

            foreach(Marque uneMarque in lesMarques)
            {
                lesMarques.Add(uneMarque);
            }

            return lesMarques;
        }
    }
}
```

My Main :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Marque> lesMarques = new List<Marque>();

        foreach (Marque uneMarque in lesMarques)
        {
            this.lesMarques.Items.Add(uneMarque.lesMarques());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for some help.
If you need more details i can send you more code.

Edit : I want create a list of "Marque" in my Class and access to it in my Form1 in a ComboBox.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Why do you need to add the items to `lesMarques` twice?

Comment: @canton7 I want to have only 1-2 lines code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I don't have to use a foreach in my class ? `

Comment: @Wakiry you are adding items to list, and them repeat the adding in `foreach` loop. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Is it really necessary that the function always returns a _new_ list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication59
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.lesMarques.Items.AddRange(SuiviEntretienMoto.Marque.lesMarques.Select(x => x.nomMarque).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
namespace SuiviEntretienMoto
{
    class Marque
    {
        public string nomMarque;

        public static List<Marque> lesMarques = new List<Marque>() {
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Beta"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Gas Gas"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Honda"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Husaberg"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Husqvarna"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Kawasaki"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "KTM"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Sherco"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Suzuki"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "TM"},
            new Marque() { nomMarque = "Yamaha"}
        };
        public Marque() { }
        public Marque(string nomMarque)
        {
            //this.nomMarque = nomMarque;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant convert <marque.lesMarques> in object []

Comment: I changed one line : this.lesMarques.Items.AddRange(marque.lesMarques.Select(x => x.nomMarque));

Comment: Same as before.

Comment: It was missing a ToArray().  See above.

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' has been thrown." to public List<Marque> lesMarques = new List<Marque>()

Comment: It has to be static.  See changes above

Comment: Thanks you very much for helping me in my learning

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can make method, creating a list of items, a `static` one and call it in your `Form1`. Since you are using `foreach` loop to go through the collection, it'll make sense to return `IEnumerable` there

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Marque> lesMarques()
{
    yield return new Marque("Beta");
    yield return new Marque("Gas Gas");
    yield return new Marque("Honda");
    yield return new Marque("Husaberg");
    yield return new Marque("Husqvarna");
    yield return new Marque("Kawasaki");
    yield return new Marque("KTM");
    yield return new Marque("Sherco");
    yield return new Marque("Suzuki");
    yield return new Marque("TM");
    yield return new Marque("Yamaha");
}
```

and iterate over them

```cs
foreach (Marque uneMarque in Marque.lesMarques())
{
    this.lesMarques.Items.Add(uneMarque);
}
```

Your current code

```cs
public List<Marque> lesMarques()
{
    List<Marque> lesMarques = new List<Marque>();
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Beta"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Gas Gas"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Honda"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Husaberg"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Husqvarna"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Kawasaki"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("KTM"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Sherco"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Suzuki"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("TM"));
    lesMarques.Add(new Marque("Yamaha"));

    foreach(Marque uneMarque in lesMarques)
    {
        lesMarques.Add(uneMarque);
    }

    return lesMarques;
}
```

adds items to `lesMarques` list twice, one by one and then in `foreach` loop again. This code will create a new `List<Marque>` every time, when you add item to combobox.

```cs
foreach (Marque uneMarque in lesMarques)
{
    this.lesMarques.Items.Add(uneMarque.lesMarques());
}
```

You don't need to create a new `List` again, when add items to combobox

Comment: And then in `Form1` it could be: `List<Marque> lesMarques = Marque.lesMarques().ToList();`

Comment: `Marque.lesMarques()` returns `IEnumerable<Marque>` which can be easily iterated through `foreach`, there is no need to cast to `List`

Comment: Agreed. Currently nothing is really "done" with these items. I thought the constructor of `Form1` would fill a list _property_, but apparently only a variable is filled and then immediately discarded...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code shorter, you can do something like this

```
 public List<Marque> lesMarques()
    {
        new string[] {
        "Beta",
        "Gas Gas",
        "Honda",
        "Husaberg",
        "Husqvarna",
        "Kawasaki",
        "KTM",
        "Sherco",
        "Suzuki",
        "TM",
        "Yamaha").Select(x => new Marque(x)).ToList();
    }
```

This method can even made static, and you can call it wherever you want, and assign it to whatever you want.